# Ending Pagination loop in PHP

Tags: pagination

```
<div id="pagination">
    <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&larr;') ?></div>
    <div class="pages">
        <?php
            global $wp_query;
            $big = 9999;
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                'show_all' => false,
                'end_size' => 1,
                'mid_size' => 5,
                'prev_next' => false,
                'prev_text' => 'Prev',
                'next_text' => 'Next',
                'type' => 'list'
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('&rarr;') ?></div>
</div>
```

Hi, I have a pagination loop setup and am choosing to display both the numbers and the prev / next links. However, I'm trying to figure out how I can end the #'s at the most recent 5 articles [1,2,3,4,5] instead of it carrying over to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. How would I go about ending it at the most recent 5 articles published on my blog?

"I'm just wanting to edit the div-class pages part so it just ends at 5." - If that makes any sense.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
'total' => min(5,$wp_query->max_num_pages),
```

**Edit:**

In the source code for `paginate_links`

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1922

the links are displayed in a loop with `$n = 1; $n <= $total; $n++` and since `%#%` is replaced with `$n` my idea is to limit the number of displayed pagelinks by restricting `$total` to the minimum of `5` and `$wp_query->max_num_pages`. Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Could you explain why this might solve the problem, and have you tested the solution?

Comment: sure: I looked at the source code for `paginate_links` and  noticed the loop `$n = 1; $n <= $total; $n++ ` and since `%#%` is replaced with  `$n`, I thought it might limit the number of displayed pagelinks by restricting `$total` to the minimum of `5` and `$wp_query->max_num_pages`. At least this was my idea ;-)

Comment: ... as part of your answer. This answer was flagged as "low quality due to length and content" by the software, which I am sure you want to avoid. It is best to provide explanation along with the raw (suggested) solution.

Comment: ok thanks @s_ha_dum, I just registered few weeks ago so I'm still learning the rules here ;-) I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :3 I couldn't find anything in the codex about this sort of thing.